# ansible result shows changed when running safe linux ad-hoc commands

Tags: ansible

When i run a ansible playbook with command option eg: command: uname -a  or run rpm -q
result shows changed =1. Suspecting some thing wrong, Please suggest.

my playbook.yml

```
- name: Check app  package configured status
  hosts: web

  tasks:
  -  name: check httpd is installed.
     command: rpm -q httpd

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
xxxxxxx              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
xxxxxx              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shell` or `command` tasks **always** trigger a change as ansible has no way to know if a binary performs something (changing a file for instance) or just displaying output on `stdout`.

If you want to check if a package is installed prefer using `package_facts` or use `yum` with `list` action. They are both somewhat verbose but does the proper job by not triggering a change, and you can register the result to filter and do proper conditions.

**package_facts** ([documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html))

```
ansible -m package_facts -i inventory/production all
myserver | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "packages": {
            ...
```

**yum with list action** ([documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-list))

```
ansible -m yum -a list=httpd -i inventory/production all
myserver | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64",
            "envra": "0:httpd-2.2.15-15.el6_2.1.x86_64",
            "epoch": "0",
            "name": "httpd",
            "release": "15.el6_2.1",
            "repo": "redhat-el-6",
            "version": "2.2.15",
            "yumstate": "available"
        },
```

If nevertheless you want to use `command` or `shell` and not trigger a change you can add `change_when: false` to the task

```
- tasks:
    name: check httpd is installed.
    command: rpm -q httpd
    changed_when: false
```

But do that at your own risk.